# Non Linear Algebraic Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If$$ abc = 4(4+a+b+c) , find $$ $$1/(2+a) +1/(2+b) + 1/(2+c).$$
My approach; put $$a=b=c=4 $$ and we are done. Looking at the symmetry of the equation, i think it is the only value that will satisfy the given equation or if otherwise, it is too difficult to get it by hit and trail.
Any better solution will be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your efforts so far.  Have you checked whether you get the same result for different values of $a$, $b$, and $c$?

Comment: $(a,b,c)=(4,8,2)$ also works.  There are infinitely many solutions, in fact.

Comment: BTW, there is nothing *linear* about these.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:Solving the equation $$abc=4(4+a+b+c)$$ for $c$ we obtain $$c=\frac{4(a+b+4)}{ab-4}$$ and we can substitute this in
$$\frac{1}{2+a}+\frac{1}{2+b}+\frac{1}{2+c}$$ we get $$\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

This is basically an exercise in simplification.

Rewrite the target expression as (after adding and simplifying): $$\frac{12+4(a+b+c)+ab+bc+ca}{8+4(a+b+c)+2(ab+bc+ca)+abc}=\frac{4(4+a+b+c)+ab+bc+ca-4}{4(4+a+b+c)+2(ab+bc+ca)+abc-8}.$$

Substituting using the given relationship results in $$\frac{abc+ ab+bc+ca-4}{2abc+2(ab+bc+ca)-8}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Set $\dfrac1{n+a}=A$ etc.

$abc=n^2(n^2+a+b+c)$

$\implies\dfrac{(1-nA)(1-nB)(1-nC)}{n^2ABC}=n^2+\dfrac1A+\dfrac1B+\dfrac1C-3n$

$1-n(A+B+C)+n^2(AB+BC+CA)-n^3ABC=n^4ABC+n^2(AB+BC+CA)-3n^3ABC$

$\iff1-n(A+B+C)=ABC\cdot n^2(n-2)$

Here $n=2$

Comment: why is n=2 in last step ?

Comment: @Carlin, Compare with the problems supplied